# Batch move folders from a subdirectory to another subdirectory that contains the same number

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have a [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKuie.jpg) and want to "merge" the folders.
What I mean with that is: if a folder exists in b\ *\ and contains the number of a folder in p\ *\ move folder from b to p.

e.g. move `b\p 11 - 20\11_abc` into `p\p_11_20\11`

I currently have:

```
@Echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f %%a IN ('dir /b "%~dp0\p\"') do (
    set "tmp=Y"
    for /f %%b IN ('dir /b "%~dp0\p\%%a\"') do if defined tmp (
        echo %%b
    )
    set "tmp="
)
```

which provides me with the numbers (e.g. 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23) Now I need a way to find out, if a folder in b\ *\ ... with that leading number exists. If yes it needs to be moved to the corresponding p\ *\ ... folder

Comment: You should look at `robocopy /?` from `cmd`

Comment: @Gerhard thank you for this recommendation. while at work today i got close to optimizing this program. I used 2 nested for loops to write down all the paths to the \b\ folders into an .txt file. Then i looped over all \p\ files and searched if a matching number is in the .txt. this is way faster but i was stuck at the move part. I tested the programm in the morning on a extra test drive and it worked. When I ran the program in the afternoon it didn't work at the move-part (tryed xcopy, move, robocopy) because I think of security reasons. I'll look more into it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It's not pretty and also not very fast, but it get's the job done.

What I basically did is to loop through every folder in \p. With the number of each folder I loop through every folder in \b. For every folder I find in \b\ I check if it begins with the number of the current \p\ folder; If yes, move the folder.

```
@Echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b "%~dp0p\"') do (
    set "tmp1=Y"
    for /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b "%~dp0p\%%a\"') do if defined tmp1 (
        set "tmp2=Y"
        for /f "delims=" %%c IN ('dir /b "%~dp0b\"') do if defined tmp2 (
            set "tmp3=Y"
            for /f "delims=" %%d IN ('dir /b "%~dp0b\%%c\"') do if defined tmp3 (
                set "tmpstr=%%d"
                set "tmpstr=!tmpstr:~0,2!"
                if "!tmpstr!"=="%%b" (
                    echo moving folder %%d to %%b ...>>log.txt
                    echo moving folder %%d to %%b ...
                    move "%~dp0b\%%c\%%d" "%~dp0p\%%a\%%b"
                )
                
            )
            set "tmp3="
        )
        set "tmp2="
    )
    set "tmp1="
)
```